# Can't Default My Parameters In My Overflowing Constructor

Tags: java

I cant default my parameters, I don't know how to set the arrays using the (this) statement.
I know that sounds stupid but I never been with words.

```
package try_Constructor;

public class NewTry {

    private int[] point1;
    private int[] point2;
    private int[] point3;

    public NewTry(){

            this(0,0, 1,0, 1,1);
    }

    public NewTry(int[] point1){

        this(point1, 1,0, 1,1);
    }

    public NewTry(int[] point1, int[] point2){

        this(point1, point2, 1,1);
    }

        public NewTry(int[] point1,int[] point2,int[] point3){

            setPointsOfTry(point1, point2, point3);
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the default constructor?

Comment: "never been with words"

Comment: Apparently he is trying to pass default values to the 4th ("full") constructor with the 3 parameters.

Comment: Just making a overflowing constructor that tack 3 arrays but I cant use the (this) statement to set the arrays/parameters of the constructor. So if I don't give object/ "I don't know ,constructor" all the parameters the it well set them atomically. If that make sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
public NewTry() { 
    this(new int[] {0,0}, new int[] {1,0}, new int[] {1,1});
}
```

etc.

That is, if you want to pass a "constant" integer array {0,0} in `Java`, you just pass it as `new int[] {0,0}`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use the [`Point` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html).  Also, always chain to the next most-specific constructor rather than breaking the chain and skipping to the end.

Then...

```
private static final Point DEFAULT_POINT_1 = new Point(0, 0);
private static final Point DEFAULT_POINT_2 = new Point(1, 0);
private static final Point DEFAULT_POINT_3 = new Point(1, 1);

public NewTry() {
    this(DEFAULT_POINT_1);
}

public NewTry(Point point1) {
    this(point1, DEFAULT_POINT_2);
}

public NewTry(Point point1, Point point2) {
    this(point1, point2, DEFAULT_POINT_3);
}

public NewTry(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3) {
    this.point1 = point1;
    this.point2 = point2;
    this.point3 = point3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the class, in this case to Newtry. Since those arrays are Fields of the Class you have to refer to them in the contructor serperatly:

```
    public Newtry(){
      this.p1 = {1,2,3...};
      this.p2 = {3,4,5...};
      this.p3 = {6,7,8...};
    }
```